# How to configure Remote JWK timeout?

Tags: spring-boot, auth0

I am using Spring boot to build API, there is an issue "JwtDecode".
"Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: connect timed out"

My project information:

- Spring boot
- Java version: 11
- Packages:

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose'

Anyone can help me for this issue?
thanks you!

Code

> 

````
```
package com.example.menu.security;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever;
import com.nimbusds.jose.util.ResourceRetriever;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/menu/items/**").permitAll() // GET requests don't need auth
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .decoder(jwtDecoder());
    }

    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()
        ));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withAudience, withIssuer);

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return jwtDecoder;

    }

}```
````

Error

> Blockquote

````
```Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-25 16:52:03.884 ERROR 85595 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.example.menu.SpringBootAuth0Application.main(SpringBootAuth0Application.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getSignatureAlgorithms(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:107) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.withProviderConfiguration(JwtDecoders.java:122) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:66) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at com.example.menu.security.SecurityConfig.jwtDecoder(SecurityConfig.java:62) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.menu.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:40) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at com.example.menu.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90da4f74.init(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: connect timed out
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:167) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar:9.8.1]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:260) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar:9.8.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getSignatureAlgorithms(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:90) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:287) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:na]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.getInputStream(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:305) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar:9.8.1]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:257) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar:9.8.1]
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:165) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.8.1.jar:9.8.1]
    ... 46 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: `JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer)` uses default hardcoded timeout (both connect and read) of 500ms and there is unfortunately no easy way to change this behavior. Using `NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri()` seems the only good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestOperations rest = builder
            .setConnectionTimeout(60000)
            .setReadTimeout(60000)
            .build();

    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).restOperations(rest).build();
    return jwtDecoder;
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-timeouts